# Powershell script to setup AAD MFA : FIDO2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, fido-u2f

We want to setup FIDO2 security key for MFA using powershell in Azure AD. We are not able to find any reference for automating this configuration. Kindly advise how can this configuration be automated.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot setup FIDO2 security key using powershell. You can however voice your interest in such a feature by up voting [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38501242-powershell-azure-ad-provisioning-and-registrations) in the Azure AD Feedback Forum.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_a9kH5HUDzIxGayh&Q_CHL=gl
>